# Citrix Automation using UIPath

Tags: automation, uipath, rpa

I am working in different kind of UI Automation and need to explore Citrix automation, can anybody suggest any live example for citrix automation so that i can give it a try and explore.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Install UiPath CE. 
Get access to another computer via Remote Desktop. Maybe boot one up via AWS or Azure.

Try to automate a program on the remote machine from your own machine via UiPath (which is installed on your own machine).

And as Poof commented, only Image (i.e. Click Image) and Hotkeys are usable. But if you use the Citrix Recording option, that should remove any activities that is not usable :)

Comment: Remmember  that you need to use keystrokes and image activities only as ther is no selectors to get from citrix ;)